# how to update order status using API in ebay?

Tags: php, ebay-api

how to update order status using php api on ebay?

from Active to Completed,
from Active to Cancelled,
from Completed to Active,
from Cancelled to Active

I tried to change order status from active to completed with following code.

```
    $service = new \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services\TradingService([
        'credentials' => $ebay_info['credentials'],
        'sandbox'     => ($sandbox == 1 ? true: false),
        'siteId'      => $siteId
    ]);
    
    $request = new \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\CompleteSaleRequestType();
    $request->RequesterCredentials = new \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
    $request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $ebay_info['authToken'];

    **$request->Shipped = true;
    $request->Paid = true;**
    $request->OrderID = $orderID;

    $response = $service->CompleteSale($request);
```

I have set paid & shipped, but it is still "active".
I am using following php ebay api
https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples

how can I change order status easily using api?